# I need to scale a website so that it will have the same functionality on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, media-queries, scaling

I need to scale a website so that it renders a reserve button on mobile phones. The website works fine on PCs and laptops but not on phones. I have tried @media (max-width: 600px) as well as  and it seems to be doing nothing at all.

Comment: You do have the [meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width,initial-scale=.75"] meta tag with width=device-width?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: @JerodBrackin I went and check your website inspect it. you have to call your classes on media query starting i would say 850px. The first thing thats affecting you is the width of the .wide class you have to put it lower width or put a max-width starting 850px on media query. then display the form into grid and adjust everything else. i noticed an inline width of 832px that will make your div overflow as well and not adjust accordingly. adjust your iframe as well while you are going to mobile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There can be problem with nesting.
For ex : You have code like this

```
 <div>
    <ul>
        <li>Good</li>
        <li>Best</li>
        <li>Fair</li>
        <li>Nice</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now there are two examples of css one wrong and one right

Wrong Css

```
div ul li {
  color:red;
}

@media (max-width:690px) {
  li {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Right Css

```
div ul li {
  color:red;
}

@media (max-width:690px) {
  div ul li {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

Comment: It maybe easier to just show it. If you go to www.cochabr.com if you scroll down to where it says find a table. This renders fine on PC however on phone it does not. The class for the button is ot-button ot-dtp-picker-button en

Comment: both css code are right ;)

Comment: both are right but I usually code in sass and when I do this My responsiveness dont work sometimes -_-